# XPath queries (such as "//th/a") returning results not under current element

Tags: python, xpath, lxml

I have the following script:

```
from lxml import etree

sample_html = '''
<body><div><table><tbody>
<tr>
  <th><a href="xxx">AAA</a></th>
  <td data-xxx="AAA-1234"></td>
  <td data-xxx="AAA-5678"></td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <th><a href="xxx">BBB</a></th>
  <td data-xxx="BBB-1234"></td>
  <td data-xxx="BBB-5678"></td>
</tr>
</tbody></table></div></body>
'''

def parse_tree(tree):
    print '============================> Parsing tree'
    rows = tree.xpath('//body/div/table/tbody/tr')
    for row in rows:
        As = row.xpath('//th/a')
        for a in As:
            print a.text
        tds = row.xpath('//td')
        for td in tds:
            print td.attrib['data-xxx']
    print


body = sample_html
tree = etree.HTML(body)
parse_tree(tree)
```

Which gives me output:

```
============================> Parsing tree
AAA
BBB
AAA-1234
AAA-5678
BBB-1234
BBB-5678
AAA
BBB
AAA-1234
AAA-5678
BBB-1234
BBB-5678
```

But I was expecting:

```
============================> Parsing tree
AAA
AAA-1234
AAA-5678
BBB
BBB-1234
BBB-5678
```

That is, I was expecting that in the `for row in rows` loop I would have **only** access to one row. Instead, `xpath` seems to be working with the whole table somehow. I obviously don't understand what is going on.

Can somebody clarify how is `xpath` handling the rows, and why is it accessing the whole table in the loop? How can I correct my script?

Comment: Your confusion about paths starting with "/" is surprisingly common, despite the fact it's exactly the same convention as is used in Unix file naming and in URI syntax.

Comment: The difference being: the FS driver has an absolute reference to use (namely, the filesystem), so absolute paths naturally refer to the root; but in my code, whenever I am using the subtree `row`, xpath should not have any way of accessing the root tree, since row *is* a subtree. This is a common programming pattern. But I guess `row` has a reference to the root tree embedded, created on the first xpath expansion, which is something that is not obvious when starting with xpath.

Comment: @jeckyll2hide, it's not actually created by anything xpath-specific at all -- an element is part of the DOM model, created on document load, well before your first XPath query was run. In terms of reasoning *why* it must be so to comply with the relevant standards -- you can also run `foo.xpath('../bar')` -- that wouldn't work either if elements existed in a vacuum. (The _Python wrapper_ for the underlying libxml element  might be created just-in-time on query, but that's an implementation detail; that underlying model is required to have links to its parent and its document).

Comment: Ignoring the standard-mandated-functionality arguments: Think how much less efficient it would be to copy the model for a subtree every time a query selects it, rather than just returning a pointer to that spot in the tree!

Comment: @jeckyll2hide, ...but, well, the standard-mandated functionality arguments are important: It's mandated by the standard that `/` refer to the document root, not the context item, so any object used to refer to an element **must** contain a link back to its containing document.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your anchoring is wrong. Instead of:

```
for row in rows:
    As = row.xpath('//th/a')
```

...use a leading `.` to refer to the current element's location in the tree:

```
for row in rows:
    As = row.xpath('.//th/a')
```

The `.//` tells the query that it's relative to the current position in the tree, whereas a leading `//` explicitly runs a recursive search from the root.

---

By the way -- why are your searches recursive at all? You could change your `//`s to just be `/`s and gain significant efficiency.

Comment: Thx. I understand I have a bug but I still do not understand the behavior of xpath: how is it possible for xpath to access the root when I am providing a row? The code is: `row.xpath('//th/a')`, which, being buggy as you say, should not give any match. Instead it matches all the rows in the table but ... `row` has no table!

Comment: @jeckyll2hide, think of it like a directory in UNIX. `/etc` is still `/etc`, even if your current directory is `/home`; it doesn't change to mean `/home/etc`, even though `./etc` does.

Answer (score 3):

Look at the [Abbreviated Syntax section of the XPath spec](http://www.w3.org/TR/xpath/#path-abbrev), specifically

- `//para` selects all the `para` descendants **of the document root** and thus selects all `para` elements in the same document as the context node
- `.//para` selects the `para` element descendants of the context node

Also,

> `//` is short for `/descendant-or-self::node()/`. For example, `//para` is short for `/descendant-or-self::node()/child::para` and so will select any para element in the document

Any XPath expression that starts with `/` starts from the document **root** node, so it cannot be restricted to descendants of the context node. In fact the context node is ignored, except to determine what document to select the root node of.

If you want to select descendants of the context node (the "current element"), as you describe, start with `.//`.